# Effect of coffee brew water concentration on further extraction in immersion brewing

Tags: extraction

In immersion brewing coffee is extracted with an increasingly saturated solution, as opposed to percolation brewing, where the extraction is performed with a continous supply of fresh water.

Because water can only extract a certain amount of solubles from the coffee and the fastest extracting compounds are dissolved first, I wanted to ask if the increasing concentration of fast extracting compounds (caffeine, volatile oils) hamper the ability of the remaining brew water to dissolve slower extracting components of the coffee bean (e.g organic acids).

Comment: I doubt that this would be the case, but it is not impossible. Consider the following from the Wikipedia (unfortunately unreferenced): " In Turkish coffee, the extremely-fine grounds are not removed and left suspended in the final beverage – resulting in an extraction of 100%, which would be considered over-extracted by Western standards. "

Comment: OTOH see the part in the Wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee_extraction) on extraction from espresso